# OptaPlanner CVRPTW - solution with capacity issue

Tags: drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I have the following CVRPTW problem and I'm trying to find a good solution with OptaPlanner. Time is in hh:mm:ss format.

My DRL file is like [this](https://raw.github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl). Moreover I defined also a hard contraint relative to the arrival before ready time.
My solver configuration is like [this](https://raw.github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml), with the difference of the termination tag:

```
<termination>
    <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
    <maximumSecondsSpend>10</maximumSecondsSpend>
    <scoreAttained>0hard/-750000soft</scoreAttained>
</termination>
```

This is the problem statement:

```
PROBLEM STATEMENT:
CustID  ReadyTIME   DueTIME     ServiceDUR  DEMAND
1       20:38:18    20:44:18    00:05:00    2   
2       20:20:53    20:26:53    00:05:00    4   
3       20:51:39    20:57:39    00:05:00    3   
4       20:20:18    20:26:18    00:05:00    6   
5       20:34:15    20:40:15    00:05:00    5   
6       20:21:40    20:27:40    00:05:00    10
```

I have 2 vehicles with both a capacity of 10 items and 1 depot.

This is the solution (customers grouped by vehicle and sorted by arrival time):

```
Vehicle 1   Capacity 10 - from Depot [1]
[6]     D: 10   Ar.T: 20:21:40  Prev.D: 00:02:21    Next.D: --:--:--

Vehicle 2   Capacity 10 - from Depot [1]
[4]     D: 6    Ar.T: 20:20:18  Prev.D: 00:01:08    Next.D: 00:02:21
[2]     D: 4    Ar.T: 20:27:42  Prev.D: 00:02:24    Next.D: 00:03:38
[5]     D: 5    Ar.T: 20:36:03  Prev.D: 00:03:21    Next.D: 00:02:09
[1]     D: 2    Ar.T: 20:43:26  Prev.D: 00:02:23    Next.D: 00:07:23
[3]     D: 3    Ar.T: 20:55:40  Prev.D: 00:07:14    Next.D: --:--:--
```

(D = demand, Ar.T = arrival time, Prev.D = distance from previous location, Next.D distance from next location)

As you can see vehicle 2 have to transport 6+4+5+2+3=20 items, which is greater than the capacity.
I don't understand why the solver suggest me this solution if there's a hard contraint relative to the capacity in the configuration.

Considering my rules, this is not an acceptable solution. Am I missing something?
Isn't there a condition where the solver provides no solution? Is it contemplated a "solver failed" termination?

Answer (score 0):

Correct if I am wrong, but you have:

- a total demand of **30** (6+4+5+2+3+10)
- a total capacity of **20** (2 vehicles with 10 each)

It's impossible to transport 30 items when your trucks can only transport 20 items. **There is no feasible solution** (so OptaPlanner delivers the best infeasible solution it finds).

Note: If the same vehicle can be used multiple times, add extra Vehicle instances and add a constraint to penalize the usage of multiple Vehicle instances with the same license plate.

Comment: It's interesting to note that sometimes easy to prove infeasibility (such as in this dataset). But often it is not (and proving infeasibility is np-complete too). For example presume 3 demands (each of demand 6) with 2 vehicles (both of capacity 10). Even though `3 * 6 < 2 * 10`, it's not feasible: no vehicle can hold more then 1 item, but here is 1 item more than vehicles.

Comment: I was assuming that OptaPlanner allows the usage of the same vehicle multiple times, so this is a wrong assumption. You suggest to add vehicle instances, but new instances have different IDs, right? So, in order to contemplate multiple-usage, should I model the problem as if I have more than 2 vehicles?

Comment: yes, the clean way would be to rename `Vehicle` to `VehicleTrip` and then add `Vehicle` again (and link every `VehicleTrip` to 1 `Vehicle. Then add a soft constraint to minimize the number trips per vehicle (squaring the count number of trips helps there).

Comment: Your suggestion is helpful, but not so easy to understand. It would be interesting to have an example, maybe in the next release :)

Comment: Anyway I'm confused, because replace `Vehicle` with `VehicleTrip` does not guarantee that different trips of a single Vehicle are planned in separated time slots (not overlapping)

Comment: Good point - I forgot that you have Time Windows too. For the arrivalTime to work properly, you 'll need to keep 1 chain per Vehicle (even if it returns multiple times to the depot to reset it's capacity). Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080537/bicycle-messenger-tsppd-with-optaplanner) for inspiration on how to lower the capacity's constraint granularity to part of the chain (from a depot until the next time it returns to the depot).

Comment: I read carefully the question you quoted, I'm sorry but I really didn't understand what to do. May you explain a bit more the solution you mentioned, please? I don't understand which are components to modify and how